# Term Enviroment Variable not set, when executing a Bash File via SSH

Tags: bash, ssh, unix, environment-variables

i am trying to run a bash script on a remote machine. If I open a ssh connection in a terminal, i can easily run the script. But when i run it like that:

> ssh user@ip < /etc/script

I get an Error:

> TERM enviroment variable not set.

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

Using ssh's `-t` option might solve your problem, since it connects a tty and sets an appropiate TERM environ variable.

`ssh -t host  < script`

Answer (score 0):

When you redirect input, ssh client probably realizes input is not connected to a TTY and so decides TERM is inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Experiment with putting these lines in `~user/.bashrc` on the destination host:

```
if [ ! ${#TERM} > 0 ]
then
    export TERM=<value>
fi
```

${#*var*} [returns the string length of variable *var*](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html). So, if the length of `TERM` is NULL (unset) or 0, you can manually set your `TERM` value.

You can also think about testing whether `$SSH_CLIENT` or `$SSH_CONNECTION` are non-zero, and only testing for a TERM value under those conditions.

Finally, this needs to go in `.bashrc` because `.bash_login` only gets run on login shells.

Comment: Unfortunatelly i can not change any files on the host/localmachine, as they are servers, that have to stay like they are. I am only allowed to change the script, which is located on both machines...

Comment: In that case, since you script is also bash, you can experiment with setting the lines in your script.